# Cassandra, how twitter automatically update tweet child object (User Object) when updating user table

Tags: database, twitter, cassandra, nosql, datastax

Please am a newbie to Cassandra. I need help to this problem I have a user table like this

```
CREATE TABLE social.user (
    userid bigint,
    userid_str text,
    username text,
    password text,
    name text,
    email text,
    phone text,
    birthday text,
    use_profile_image boolean,
    use_background_image boolean,
    background_image_url text,
    profile_image_url text,
    background_image_position text,
    profile_url text,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid)
);

CREATE TABLE social.tweet (
    feedid bigint,
    feedid_str text,
    content text,
    creation_date text,
    source text,
    comment_count int,
    like_count int,
    liked boolean,
    permalink text,
    user FROZEN,
    PRIMARY KEY (feedid)
);
CREATE TYPE social.user (
    userid bigint,
    userid_str text,
    username text,
    password text,
    name text,
    email text,
    phone text,
    birthday text,
    use_profile_image boolean,
    use_background_image boolean,
    background_image_url text,
    profile_image_url text,
    background_image_position text,
    profile_url text,
);
```

how can i automatically update type user in the tweet when a user update is profile in the user table. Like twitter when you update your name or fullname automatically your tweet name or fullname update

Comment: Create a [trigger](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateTrigger.html)?

Comment: You have to do it from the application layer.

Comment: Am grateful for the replies. I just read the trigger now but can I have a working example using trigger to achieve this. Am using java.